# Symfony : How can i display and handle many edit form on sigle page

Tags: forms, symfony, user-interface, symfony-forms, forum

I'm stuck with the following problem.

I'm using Symfony 4.2.3 to build a forum ( a piece of a bigger project )

I've made a ForumController who handle :

- Forum Home page ( show forumCategories with their forumSubCategories )
- Forum Category page ( show selected forumCategory with her forumSubCategories )
- Forum Sub Category page ( show selected forumSubCategory with her forumTopics )
- Forum Topic page ( show selected forumTopic with her forumMessage( i.e. reaction ) )

What i want is to implement an edit button who not redirect to an edit page but $(this).slidedown an edit form in a div. This button is display only if the ForumMessage author is the current login user.
So if this user have reply many time to the topic, I need just as many buttons ( and form ). After click on edit, the page can be reload and entity update.

For create / edit with redirection i've understood how to.

The problem was, how to handle an unknown number of edit MessageType form ( and so unknown form id ).

I've try to create an array of ForumMessage link to an array of MessageType Form.
But when i have to give the .createView() of each form to twig, my brain glitch.

So please, how can i have many edit form on sigle page( each link to the refered entity ) and handle them in my controller to .flush modification ?

I already implement JS function for the diplaying of the button and linked div.

The showTopic method of my ForumController.php :

```
/**
 * @Route("/forum/category={idCategory}/subCategory={idSubCategory}/topic={idTopic}", name="topic")
 * @ParamConverter("topic", options={"id" = "idTopic"})
 * @param $idCategory
 * @param $idSubCategory
 * @param $idTopic
 * @param Request $request
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function showTopic($idCategory, $idSubCategory, $idTopic, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, UserInterface $user = null) {
    $topic = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ForumTopic::class)->find($idTopic);
    $userMessages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ForumMessage::class)->findBy([
        'author' => "Kaarie",
        'forumTopic' => $topic
    ]);

    // Nouveau message sur un topic
    $message = new ForumMessage();
    $form = $this->createForm(ForumMessageType::class, $message);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $message->setAuthor($user->getUsername())
                ->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime())
                ->setForumTopic($topic);
        $manager->persist($message);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('topic', [
            'idCategory' => $idCategory,
            'idSubCategory' => $idSubCategory,
            'idTopic' => $topic->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    // Editer un message
    $editMessage = new ForumMessage();
    $editForm = $this->createForm(ForumMessageType::class, $editMessage);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $manager->persist($editMessage);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('topic', [
            'idCategory' => $idCategory,
            'idSubCategory' => $idSubCategory,
            'idTopic' => $topic->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('forum/showTopic.html.twig',[
        'idCategory' => $idCategory,
        'idSubCategory' => $idSubCategory,
        'topic' => $topic,
        'messageForm' => $form->createView(),
        'editForm' => $editForm->createView(),
        'userMessage' => $userMessages,
    ]);
}
```

The class MessageType in MessageType.php

```
class ForumMessageType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder
        ->add('content')
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
    ;
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
      $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ForumMessage::class,
      ]);
   }
}
```

The twig part who display Message from showTopic.html.twig

```
    <ul>
        {% for message in topic.ForumMessages %}
            <li>
                {{ message.author }},</br>
                {{ message.content }}
                {% if app.user %}
                    {% if is_granted("ROLE_MODERATOR") %}

                        <button>Moderate</button> {# TODO: moderation d'un message #}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if app.user.username == message.author %}
                        <div  class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 1em; display: none">
                            <h3>Etidé votre réponse :</h3>
                            {{ form_start(editForm) }}
                            {{ form_row(editForm.content) }}
                            {{ form_row(editForm.submit, {'label': 'Editer'}) }}
                            {#<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editer</button>#}
                            {{ form_end(editForm) }}
                        </div>
                        <button id="buton_EditTopic">Modifier</button>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

For any other ressources please ask me !

Comment: Try to read more about Collections - This is what you need to achieve this. Read @documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Thank to you i leran cool things for the future of my project ( tag for exemple ).
But doesn't work for me.
I found a gread exemple of what can i do with collection and JS [her](https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/advanced/collectionOfCollections).
In my case i think i need differents form instances ( depend on how many message have wrote de user ) in different places ( indepandante on submit )
Collection are for one form where we can add or remove input/form ?

Comment: The main usage of a collection is, to update multiple datasets ( most, entites from a relation but not limited to that) with one request. The main question is, do you want edit multiple at once, or want you edit one from list, save and then edit another? Because, if you want to have a form, when you click on the edit button, you should not use collections or multiple forms - then you have to load the form and push that rendered code to your existing html (ajax request).

Comment: So in my case, i have to : 1 - limite edit buton to only one active at time. 2 - display the only "edit" ForumMessage form i give to the page on the active edit buton area. (with a hidden input to know wich entity i have edit ). 3 - On save buton click, redirect to # and precess podification on my controller ?
Yes i only want to edit one message at time, and reload page each time.
The way you try to help me is very nice, thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be (maybe some tweaking is necessary, didnt test it)

Short Hand explanation:
The list will only contain containers. When you edit one message, you load only the form and push that to this specific container. If you edit this and press save, it would send the form per ajax request to the controller. If the form is valid, it will return then a json repsonse instead of html ...

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/forum/category={idCategory}/subCategory={idSubCategory}/topic={idTopic}", name="topic")
 * @ParamConverter("topic", options={"id" = "idTopic"})
 * @param $idCategory
 * @param $idSubCategory
 * @param $idTopic
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function showTopic(
    $idCategory, 
    $idSubCategory, 
    $idTopic, 
    Request $request, 
    ObjectManager $manager, 
    UserInterface $user = null
)
{
    $topic = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ForumTopic::class)->find($idTopic);
    $userMessages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ForumMessage::class)->findBy([
        'author' => "Kaarie",
        'forumTopic' => $topic
    ]);

    return $this->render('forum/showTopic.html.twig',[
        'idCategory' => $idCategory,
        'idSubCategory' => $idSubCategory,
        'topic' => $topic,
        'userMessage' => $userMessages,
    ]);
}

/**
 * With this, you can create and mod Topics
 * @Route("/forum/messages/{forumMessage}/mod-message", name="message.mod", defaults={"forumMessage":0})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param ForumMessage $forumMessage
 * @return mixed
 */
public function modTopic(
    Request $request, 
    Objectmanager $manager, 
    ForumMessage $forumMessage=null
)
{

    if($formMessage == null) {
        $forumMessage = new ForumMessage();
        /* set Additional Info here, maybe User, IP Adress or whatever */
    }
    $editForm = $this->createForm(ForumMessageType::class, $forumMessage);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $manager->persist($forumMessage);
        $manager->flush();

        return new JsonRepsonse(['status'=>true, 'message' => "ForumMessage save successfull"]);
    }


    return $this->render('mod.message.html.twig',[
        'messageForm' => $editForm->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

FormType:

```
class ForumMessageType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder
        ->add('content')
    ;
   }

   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
      $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => ForumMessage::class,
      ]);
   }
}
```

list.html.twig

```
<ul>
    {% for message in topic.ForumMessages %}
        <li>
            {{ message.author }},</br>
            {{ message.content }}
            {% if app.user %}
                {% if is_granted("ROLE_MODERATOR") %}

                    <button>Moderate</button> {# TODO: moderation d'un message #}
                {% endif %}
                {% if app.user.username == message.author %}
                    <div id="modMessageContainer{{ message.id }}"  class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 1em; display: none">
                    </div>
                    <button onclick="modMessage(this);" 
                         data-attr-url="{{ path('message.mod'.{'forumMessage':message.id}) }}" 
                         data-attr-container="#modMessageContainer{{ message.id }}"
                    >Modifier</button>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<script>
    function modMessage(element)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(element).attr('data-attr-url'),
            success: function(data) {
                $($(element).attr('data-attr-container')).html(data).show();
            }
        });
    }

    function saveMessage(element)
    {
        var container = $(element).attr('data-attr-container');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(element).attr('data-attr-url'),
            type:'POST',
            data: $(container +' form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                if(typeof data == 'object' && data instanceof Object && !(data instanceof Array)) {
                    if(data.status) {
                        location.reload()
                    } else {
                        alert(data.message);
                    }
                } else {
                    $(container).show();
                    $('#modMessage').replaceWith($(data).find('#modMessage'));
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

mod.html.twig

```
<div>
    <div id="modMessage">
        <h3>Etidé votre réponse :</h3>
        {{ form_start(editForm) }}
        {{ form_row(editForm.content) }}
        {{ form_row(editForm.submit, {'label': 'Editer'}) }}
        {#<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editer</button>#}
        {{ form_end(editForm) }}
        <div style="text-align:right">
            <button onclick="saveMessage(this);" 
                 type="button" 
                 class="btn btn-success" 
                 data-attr-container="modMessageContainer{{ message.id }}" 
                 data-attr-url="{{ path('message.mod', {'forumMessage':message.id}) }}"
             >Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Thank a lot**, i gonna work with this, and learn more about ajax ! I'll be back to give some feedback.
You save a master piece of my `school project`.

Comment: Did add some fix, because the saveMessage will cause some problem - but no it should work.